# Puppeteer Cant go into iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, puppeteer

I am struggling for hours trying to get to the iframe but I just can't type in this box for some reason. The HTML does not show input on the page or in the iframe this is the code I tried and was the closest but not really getting to the box to type. this is the part of the HTML I try to get into.
[inspect from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa5Ri.png)

and here is the code I am using

const iframeHandle = await page.$$('iframe');

const contentFrame = await iframeHandle[2].contentFrame();

const tester = await contentFrame.$$('#rte');

and when I run

console.log(tester.length);

I get 1 so i am getting into the iframe but I dont know how to type with in it so far I can see its only an emtpy

tag in it

Maybe I am just missing something small any help will be most appreciated

Comment: What's the box you want to type in?

Comment: This is missing a [mcve]. Without the site, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `frame` call.

So from your code

```
const iframeHandle = await page.$$('iframe');
await this.browser.frame(iframeHandle);
```

Or something of the sort, according to your code should get you into that iframe.

Comment: I think my problem is more where is the input I posted a pic with the question with the sites source maybe its something with the selector or its javascript that I cant get into

Answer (score 0):

Try focus on the input and type

```
const cardElement = await paymentFrame.$('#cardNumber');

// Input is focused.
await cardElement.focus();
```

or this should work

```
const frames = await page.frames();
  let iframe = frames.find(f => f.name() === 'any_iframe');
  const textInput = await iframe.$('#textInput');
  textInput.click(); // this focusses on the element
  textInput.type('description text');
```